# Ubuntu 20.04 - how to force screen resolution on a headless machine usin RealVNC

Tags: screen, display-resolution

I'm using an old PC to run some processes that I will connect remotely using VNC.
All is working as expected, but when booting without a dsiplay, resolotion is set to minimum (640X480  which makes it very hard to handle.

Is there a way to force a display resolution ?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the VNC server do you use. Some of them have an optional parameter `-geometry` or any to force the desktop resolution (see man page of your VNC server).

In a case, your VNC server is vnc4server you can start the desktop `1` (port 5901) with the following command:

```
vnc4server :1 -geometry 1366x768
```

Replace 1366x768 with your desired resolution.

Run this command via SSH or via startup script (as normal user, not root).

Comment: any reason for such specific dimensions ?

Comment: and - where to put this command ?

Comment: there isn't any reason. Use the resolution of your client host display. Run this command on server side (via ssh or add as the startup script)

Comment: What is your VNC server? How do you strart a VNC desktop with 640x480 resolution?

Comment: RealVNC is the server

Comment: I don’t understand the second part of your question- The screen resolution is set as a default when display is not connected

Comment: I had never used RealVNC server, so can't help you with them. If you need help with RealVNC specify it in your question. You can use VNC servers from Ubuntu repositories, such as `vnc4server`, `linuxvnc`, `tigervnc`, `tightvncserver` etc. To install `vnc4server` run `sudo apt-get install vnc4server` and google it how to set up it. Or google how to set resolution in RealVNC server configs